Pydeck ScatterplotLayer in Streamlit Maps All Points are set to (0,0) Even with Valid Coordinates
Description
I'm working with a Pydeck ScatterplotLayer in Streamlit to display geographic points on a map. However, all points are being plotted at the coordinate (0, 0) (latitude 0, longitude 0), even though my data contains valid latitude and longitude values.
Here’s a brief outline of my setup:

I'm loading a dataset from a .tsv file, which contains institution names, foundation years, and geographic coordinates (latitude and longitude).
I’ve verified that the latitude and longitude columns are numeric (float64) and contain valid values (no NaN or missing data).
Despite this, when I render the map, all points are shown at the default (0, 0) location.
Ensured that columns names are exactly the same
Tried multiple ways of setting "get_position" at pdk.Layer()

Code:
from pprint import pprint

import numpy as np

import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import pydeck as pdk

# Load the dataset
file_path = 'maps/data/processed/locations.proc.tsv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t')


# Only select necessary columns and ensure they are Arrow-compatible
valid_data = data.dropna(subset=['Multi-site institution - Latitude', 'Multi-site institution - Longitude'])
valid_data['Institution Name'] = valid_data['Institution Name'].astype(str)
valid_data['Multi-site institution - Latitude'] = pd.to_numeric(valid_data['Multi-site institution - Latitude'], errors='coerce')
valid_data['Multi-site institution - Longitude'] = pd.to_numeric(valid_data['Multi-site institution - Longitude'], errors='coerce')

# Prepare the cleaned data for Pydeck
map_data = valid_data[['Institution Name', 'Multi-site institution - Latitude', 'Multi-site institution - Longitude']].dropna()

# Convert DataFrame to list of dicts for pydeck
map_data.loc[:,"coordinates"]= map_data['Multi-site institution - Latitude'].astype(str) +","+ map_data['Multi-site institution - Longitude'].astype(str)


# Create pydeck Deck object
view_state = pdk.ViewState(
    latitude=map_data['Multi-site institution - Latitude'].mean(),
    longitude=map_data['Multi-site institution - Longitude'].mean(),
    zoom=5,
    pitch=40
)

st.write(map_data)

# Render the map with pydeck
layer=pdk.Layer(
        'ScatterplotLayer',
        data=map_data,
        # get_position="[Multi-site institution - Latitude, Multi-site institution - Longitude]",
        get_position=[map_data.columns[-2],map_data.columns[-3]],
        get_radius=5000,
        get_fill_color=[255, 0, 0],  # Red points for visibility
        pickable=True,
        auto_highlight=True
    )
r = pdk.Deck(
    layers=[
        layer
    ],
    initial_view_state=view_state,
    tooltip={
        "html": "<b>{Institution Name}</b>",
        "style": {"backgroundColor": "steelblue", "color": "white"}
    }
)
r.to_html("smth.html")
st.pydeck_chart(r)

Issue:

Despite all my attempts, all points are plotted at coordinates (0, 0).

Has anyone faced a similar issue with pydeck setting all coordinates to zero? Any advice or troubleshooting steps would be appreciated. I am going to shoot my self with a door knob...
Data (tsv):
Foundation year Institution Name    Institutional website   Multi-site institution - City   Multi-site institution - Latitude   Multi-site institution - Longitude
1457    Albert-Ludwigs-Universität Freiburg http://www.uni-freiburg.de/ Freiburg im Breisgau    47.993544   7.84595
1386    Ruprecht-Karls-Universität Heidelberg   http://www.uni-heidelberg.de/   Heidelberg  49.411282   8.706172
1818    Universität Hohenheim   http://www.uni-hohenheim.de Stuttgart   48.711712   9.211786

